# Why does the "push" instruction give me an "invalid opcode" exception? (osdev)

Tags: c, assembly, operating-system, executable, osdev

#### What I'm Doing & What Works

I've been working on my own 32 bit toy kernel in C for a while, and lately I've been fiddling around with executing dynamically defined code, as I'd like to add a binary loader soon.

In particular what I'm doing for now is creating char arrays containing the opcodes of a series of  instructions, copying them to the beginning of a new (executable) page and appending the opcode of a `ret` instruction, e.g.:

```c
char div_by_zero [] =   {   0xba, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,         // mov 0x0, edx
                            0xb8, 0xfa, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,         // mov 0xfa, eax
                            0xb9, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,         // mov 0x0, ecx
                            0xf7, 0xf1                            // div ecx ---> DIV BY 0
                        }; 


void exec_test(){
    char* thing = (char*) get_virtual_address(0,1, 0);
    char postamble [] = {0xc3};         // ret

    char *code = div_by_zero;
    /* [...] omitted: copying to 'thing' and adding the 'postamble' at the end...  */
    
    __asm__("call %0" :: "m" (thing));    // Starts executing the "string" (lol)
}
```

This one was the first one I tried, which as expected resulted in a `DIVISION BY ZERO`.

Then I tried the following:

```c
// movb   $0x41,0x1000
char write_A_on_1000 [] = { 0xc6, 0x05, 0x00, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x41 };
```

And then printed the character at memory location `0x1000`, which as expected was a capital `A`.

#### The problem

Another one I tried, seemingly quite simple, was the following:

```c
char push_one [] = {0x6a, 0x01};
```

Which should simply push the integer `1` on the stack. Unlike the other examples, this one does not seem to work. In fact, it gives me an `INVALID OPCODE` exception.

One of the things I tried to do was to write the `push` explicitly, by subtracting 4 to the stack pointer etc (which also resulted in an `INVALID OPCODE`), but then again, my future loader should be able to execute `push` just fine, so I should really fix this..

(Btw, I'm targeting `i386` machines and currently using QEMU to run the kernel.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that the return address is stored on the stack.  If you push something on the stack and then return, you'll return to whatever address you pushed on the stack.  This is unlikely to go well.

Make sure to keep the stack balanced when performing experiments like this.  For example, you could pop off the value you just pushed:

```
/* push $1; pop %eax */
char push_one [] = {0x6a, 0x01, 0x58};
```

You can observe this by investigating the return value, which the compiler expects to be in `eax`.

Comment: Yours works fine! I'm still not entirely sure why an unbalanced stack would cause an `INVALID OPCODE`, I'd expect something like a `PAGE FAULT`, since it returns to some random address..

Comment: Ah no wait, guess I get it; it may by chance get to some readable memory and find that it's junk, hence no page fault, but it can't parse the opcode... Right?

Comment: @mell_o_tron Yes, that's a likely explanation.  You could explore what's there at address 1.  Likely some address that's part of the real mode interrupt vector table.

Comment: @mell_o_tron: If you don't have a dev setup with a debugger that lets you single-step this code and/or see the situation when the #UD exception was raised, that's the first thing you should fix.  Bochs is good for this kind of thing, with a built-in debugger that knows about real vs. protected mode.  QEMU can also act as a GDB-remote, but it might not be as good for seeing the context before an exception.

Comment: Anyway, yeah, if address `cs:1` is in a readable segment (and page if enabled), then executing bytes from there could eventually lead to one that isn't a valid instruction.  (especially if you don't enable x87 and SSE with control register bits, so those opcodes will #UD.)

Comment: Yeah @PeterCordes I've been trying to use GDB with QEMU but I had a few problems getting it to recognize my kernel binary

Comment: You can single-step asm without that; the instructions exist in the guest memory.  In fact you *want* to look at them, not the binary file, in case a bug overwrote machine code in memory and that's why it's not running as you expect.  (Not the case here; pushing a new return address for `ret` to pop into EIP is more than sufficient to explain running bytes that weren't intended to be instructions.  But those bytes might have been stored into memory at run-time so you do actually want the disassembly of what's in the guest memory in this case, too, if you're curious about the details.)

Comment: @mell_o_tron: As I said, Bochs' built-in debugger is generally regarded as the best, but with GDB you should still be able to use `layout asm` (instead of `layout src` or `layout reg`).  With some `layout next` commands, you can get to a view with disassembly and registers.

Comment: I guess I'll try Bochs out, thanks!